# How to do an exhaustive switch statement with ambient enum types

Tags: typescript

I have the following function:

```js
function mapPlaceToEmoji(place: Place): string {
    switch (place) {
        case Place.FIRST:
            return '';
        case Place.SECOND:
            return '';
        case Place.THIRD:
            return '';
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine if I use a non-ambient enum:

```js
enum Place {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
}
```

However, it doesn't work with an ambient enum:

```js
declare enum Place {
    FIRST,
    SECOND,
    THIRD,
}
```

I get the following error:

> Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.(2366)

How can I do an exhaustive switch statement with ambient enum types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known bug in TypeScript; see [microsoft/TypeScript#16977](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16977).  Until and unless this gets fixed, you can work around it by explicitly setting the values like this:

```
declare enum Place {
  FIRST = 0,
  SECOND = 1,
  THIRD = 2,
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEIB2BXAtvACtMCDeAUPPAGICSASgMoAq8AvPAAwA0R8VAogMIDyAcgBEG8AIxtiNABKVhjAExsAvgQIAzFEjAAXAJYB7JPDRQADtii4a+zmn0ArXQApTOEAC4sbgJSeAztowukgA5vCExH4A7rraYAAW8C4+4ezEYFB+CBa4AHTk1DTuacTwcNooMEYA5IB8G4Diu9UA3CUZWV6WILlcfELFpaXllTW1gBK7za2Z2W650rL9A2UgFVXwdYCSuxPEKioEQA)